# Custom Authentication in Django with Email

Tags: python, django

i have to do this task

For the current project, create the ability to log in with email or username, under these conditions, you should expand the input elements of the registration form and add the ability to log in by email, and then during the review if one of the two matches. The user name or email status should be checked and the user will be allowed to enter

and i search a lot about this but i cant find them useful

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def login_view(request):
   if not request.user.is_authenticated:
      if request.method == 'POST':
          form = AuthenticationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
             username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
             password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
             user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
             if user is not None:
                 login(request, user)
                 return redirect('/')
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    context = {'form': form}    
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)
else:
    return redirect('/')

@login_required
def logout_view(request):
  logout(request)
  return redirect('/')

def register_view(request):
   if not request.user.is_authenticated:
     if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {"form":form})
else:
    return redirect('/')
```

i dont have a forms.py and i dont much code in models